# How do I pass javascript variable to Ajax script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In an html button I have this onclick event:

```
onclick='javascript:updateStatus(59)'
```

Then I have this function

```
function updateStatus(){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/update-status.php',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});

    return false; 
}
```

And this is update-status.php

```
$sql = "UPDATE requests SET status='Closed' WHERE requestid=$requestid";    
    $updatestatus = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (!$updatestatus) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
    } else {    
    return "success!";
    }
```

Ultimately, I want the number from the original onclick event (in this example it's 59, but could be any number) to get passed into the $requestid variable in update-status.php.

What is the best/proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: First step is to add a parameter to your `updateStatus` function: `function updateStatus(requestId)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out to use "data" in the function after more googling, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the JQuery AJAX function, just use another parameter in the configuration object, `data`. You're also missing an argument for the function.

```
    function updateStatus(i){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: 'requestid='+i,
    url: '/update-status.php',
    success: function(data){
        // callback function
    }
});

    return false; 
}
```

You could also create a map and send the map, like so

```
...
    data: {"requestid" : i},
...
```

You're server side code should be updated though. You don't want to be using input from the client without first sanitizing it. This opens up the threat for SQL Injection attacks.

for example, what if the value of requestid is

```
1 or '1'='1' --
```

or

```
1; drop table requests
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take the passed in argument in your javascript function and send it to your PHP script like this:

```
function updateStatus(id){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/update-status.php',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(data){

    }
   });
    return false; 
}
```

In your PHP access it through `$_POST['id']`. However, make sure you escape the value to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
$requestid = $_POST['id'];
```